# MariaDB select with group_concat() - Out of memory

Tags: mariadb, centos7

we have centos 7 machine with mariadb installed.

When I run:

```
SELECT h.id,
       h.name,
       group_concat(distinct d.name ORDER BY d.name SEPARATOR " ") AS descriptions 
FROM inventar h 
LEFT JOIN descriptions d ON(FIND_IN_SET(d.id, h.description_id) > 0) GROUP BY h.id,h.description_id 
ORDER BY h.name asc;
```

> ERROR 5 (HY000): Out of memory (Needed 65535816 bytes)

I read that it probably limit of the size of temporary table.

I checked the size:

MariaDB [wexac_hosts]> show variables like "%table_size%";

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| max_heap_table_size | 1048576000 |
| tmp_disk_table_size | 18446744073709551615 |
| tmp_memory_table_size | 12572426240 |
| tmp_table_size | 12572426240 |

it's bigger then 65535816 bytes.

Which mariadb variable should I increase?

Comment: How much RAM is available to your server?  TOP or HtOP from the OS will tell you.

Comment: MySQL (8.0.30) produces warning like: `Row 284 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()`, and no error. MariaDB (10.5.12) does do the same but on a later row `Row 165670 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()` (Both tests ran on a table which should be a copy of each other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) that's running out of memory, you need to increase [`group_concat_max_len`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#group_concat_max_len).

From the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) documentation:

> The maximum returned length in bytes is determined by the
> group_concat_max_len server system variable, which defaults to 1M (>=
> MariaDB 10.2.4) or 1K (<= MariaDB 10.2.3).

Comment: This setting, using MySQL, defaults to 1024. (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len )